# Redirection URI does not match the one registered for Mendeley API client application

Tags: oauth, mendeley

I am trying to set up an OAuth2 standard authorisation process to Mendeley API from our Java web application. The following URL gets called (I've blanked out my client id in this post):

https://api.mendeley.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxx&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapp%2Fconnect%2Fmendeley&scope=all&state=887e0b43-b8e7-41b3-a120-6063e4bdfed3

but I get an error:

```
{"error_message":"Redirection URI does not match the one registered for this application"}
```

I have checked this redirect URI in my Mendeley 'My applications' page and the redirect_uri value is  is exactly the same string of characters as is shown in the page. Please could you tell me if there is  anything wrong with this URL, or if the encoding should be different?

Thanks for any advice

Richard

Answer (score 1):

This was my error - I was escaping the URL in the MyApplications section in Mendeley dev web page. So, the URL you register as your callback should be the verbatim website URL -  only the redirect URL request parameter as it is sent in the authorization request should be encoded.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same thing. I'm using django rather than java. I can successfully retrieve a code with my redirect_url, but cannot exchange it for a token. I've http-encoded my string I pass, but not what I entered at Mendeley's site. I think I've done exactly what you've done. But still no luck. If you have any updates, I'd be happy to see them.

Comment: I am having the same trouble with Rails.

Comment: Correct answer. I would like to emphasise "your callback should be the **verbatim** website URL". In my case we were using `https://www.` instead of `https://`